# Как сделать адаптивный слайдер разделённый на две части?

Tags: jquery, css, вёрстка

Как сделать адаптивный слайдер, изображённый на рисунке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. все блоки идентичные, в каждом блоке находится title и price + свой бэкграунд для каждого блока.
На больших экранах нужно, чтобы слайдер был разделён на 2 части как на рисунке, в правой части должно быть 4 маленьких блока.
На мобилках нужно чтобы слайдер был из одного блока.
Можно ли это реализовать только на css, или нужно использовать js ?

**P.S.**
т.е. на изображении один слайд, разделённый на две части, и таких слайдов может быть много
на мобилках, при прокрутке к следующему слайду, 4 маленьких слайда будут пропущены, т.к. они находятся в одном большом слайде

Comment: Делайте по одному слайду, а в слайд помещайте любое кол-во элементов, хоть 1, хоть 5 как на примере

Comment: @DaemonHK, так если я в один слайд размещу к примеру 5 слайдов, то на мобилках, при прокрутке к следующему слайду, эти 5 слайдов будут пропущены, т.к. все 5 слайдов размещены в одном слайде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем вас не устраивает [любой слайдер](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider#responsive-options), который поддерживает адаптивность? Указываете в качестве слайдов нужные вам блоки, а уже в них размещаете что хотите и как хотите - хоть 4, хоть 100 элементов.

Поидее получается так, что вам нужно сделать следующим образом - при мобильном - отображать просто сам слайдер и листать по 1 элементу. А уже когда нужна "полная версия" - то уже ручками считать какой должен получиться слайд, на сколько проматывать и т.д. Сразу скажу - это не работающий вариант так как вам надо, но думаю суть происходящего должна быть понятна.

```js
var slider = tns({
    container: '.slide',
    items: 5,
    slideBy: 'page',
    autoplay: true,
    onInit: function(sl){
     console.log(sl);
     var wrapper = sl.container.parentNode,
       widthTotal = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width,
        widthColumn = widthTotal / 4,
       items = sl.container.querySelectorAll('.item'),
       counter = 0;
      console.log(widthColumn * Math.ceil(items.length / 5))
      sl.container.style.width = widthColumn * Math.ceil(items.length / 5) + 'px';
      while (items.length > counter) {
       if (counter % 5 === 0){
         items[counter].classList.add('big');
        }
        counter++;
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.item{
    width: auto !important;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.slide{
    height: 300px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
    grid-auto-columns: 100px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.big{
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.7.1/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.7.1/tiny-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="item big">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item big">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item big">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item big">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
  <div class="item">19</div>
  <div class="item">20</div>
</div>
```

Comment: может быть неправильно изложил суть вопроса, на изображении выше это один слайд, а таких слайдов может быть много, но на мобилках не должно быть разделение на две части одного слайда

Comment: Тогда непонятна суть простановки тега jQuery, если это все можно сделать с помощью flex. Т.е. чистый CSS. А можно и на grid сделать. Все зависит от того как это должно вести себя на адаптиве

Comment: так я ведь вроде объяснил как должно быть на мобилках. На мобилках в одном слайде должен быть один блок а не 5, как на больших экранах. На больших экранах должно быть 5 блоков в одном слайде, на мобилках должен быть 1 блок в одном слайде

Comment: есть конечно вариант, чтобы в одном слайде в правой части как-бы дублировать 4 следующих слайда, и на мобилках эту правую часть скрывать. Это решение мне известно. На php это не сложно будет потом реализовать?

Comment: @word В таком случае вам нужно вручную писать обработчик который будет формировать слайды. Пример прикрепил к ответу. Но можно и другим способом - смотреть ширину экрана и если широкий - сперва пробегаться по всем слайдам, группировать их в отдельные блоки по 5 штук, а верстка...а верстку можете как раз взять ту что у меня. И затем уже инициализировать слайдер.

Comment: @word Если дублировать следующие 4 слайда - то получится несколько не то. Будет тогда слайд и справа превью следующих 4-х слайдов, а вам, как я понимаю, нужно не это. Тут скорее нужно все-таки сперва группировать по 5 блоков в 1 слайд (если ширина экрана больше указанной) и затем инициализировать слайдер. Иначе просто инициализировать слайдер.